# Run piece of code based on a feature

Tags: sensors, sketch, variables

I am an engineering student completely new at using Arduino so my following question might be silly but still. I do not think you'll need to get the entire code so I am only going to expose the idea.
So basically, I would like a customer to choose a feature between three of them (let's name them 1, 2, 3). Depending on the feature he chose, the corresponding `setup()` and the corresponding `loop()` have to run. For example, if he chooses the second feature, in the main `setup()`, the `setup2()` has to run and in the main `loop()`, the `loop2()` has to run only. The other `setup()` functions and `loop()` functions have to do nothing. I first thought I could do this using switch cases but I am looking for another way to implement that as a teacher told me this method would take too much time.

```
void setup() {

      setup1(); //only runs if 1st feature chosen
      setup2();
      setup3();
}




void loop() {

      loop1(); //only runs if 1st feature chosen
      loop2();
      loop3();
}
```

And also, I wrote the three `setup()` and the three `loop()` in different files (of course, `setup1()` is in the same file as a `loop1()`, etc., ...). Is it possible to include them in the main file (for instance, like `<#include nameoffile.h`)?

Comment: What physical method are you using to determine which feature has been chosen?

Comment: @Majenko I'll use a web-based configurator for the customer to chose. Its name is MQTT

Comment: So the device will subscribe to an MQTT topic and receive a retained message to get the configuration? I would say you want to implement a Finite State Machine, since the whole "configuration" system is itself another configuration in its own right.

Comment: I don’t understand what your teacher is talking about. Seems to me that a switch-case would work just fine.

Comment: @Majenko yes that is the idea! I have never heard of a Finite State Machine but I am going to make some research about it.

Comment: @Gerben I am going to try this way too then. Just have to figure out how I am going to retrieve the feature chosen by the customer

Comment: A Switch-Case usually forms the heart of a Finite State Machine. It's the simplest way of implementing one. https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine

Comment: @majenko thanks, I'll give a look to this link! i really thought I could avoid Switch cases thought but I guess I'll have to deal with it

Comment: do you really have to call setup after every feature change? or could you just initialize all features at once and just switch what you are using?

Comment: @mystery I could indeed Switch the variables i am using!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
typedef enum { FEATURE1, FEATURE2, FEATURE3 } Feature;

//implement these
Feature getFeatureFromUser(){}
void setup1(){}
void setup2(){}
void setup3(){}
void loop1(){}
void loop2(){}
void loop3(){}

void setup() {
  Feature f = getFeatureFromUser();

  switch (f) {
    case FEATURE1:
      setup1();
      while (true) {
        loop1();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
      }
    case FEATURE2:
      setup2();
      while (true) {
        loop2();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
      }
    case FEATURE3:
      setup3();
      while (true) {
        loop3();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
      }
  }
}

//never reached
void loop() {}
```

It's good to know that there's no hard rules about how the Arduino functions should be used. Examples like this demonstrate how Arduino's standard requirements of `void setup()` and `void loop()` don't quite match every use case.

**EDIT**: The serialEventRun lines are normally called behind the scenes after each execution of Arduino's normal `loop()`, so adding them here will result in the standard behavior of serial events

Comment: yes that is the idea! thank you very much for helping, this is really helpful! but what do you mean by the void loop() is never reached, why is that? arduino seems much clearer this way

Comment: After one of the options in the switch statement matches, and the corresponding setup function is run, the loop# function will be called forever inside a while loop. Therefore it will stay in that loop forever and never reach Arduino's loop() function. The blocks in the switch statement are very similar to how Arduino's setup() and loop() work behind the scenes.

Comment: ok that's clear now! thks I'll try this way then

Comment: The downside of that method is that it breaks serial event handling. If you don't use serial events, then that's not an issue.

Comment: @Majenko i thought about it too as I may have other operations to do. Indeed, after the first Setup(), three others Options setup11(), setup12() and Setup13() with their own Loops should run, depending again on the customer's choice (choice could be 11, 12,13) don't know if that is still clear

Comment: @Majenko I also just found an interesting article about Software product line Engineering. If you've heard about it, do you think I could take ideas from this concept?

Comment: @Majenko I just updated to add serial event handling

Comment: I wish the real world was this simple. The proposed method above requires the total sum of memory resources. If that is available no problem but in most cases the total sum of, for instance, memory for all the global variables is not available. Instead each feature would like to use the memory available, and not need to share with features that are not enabled.

Comment: @MikaelPatel The OP wanted to select a feature at runtime. Otherwise this could easily be done with preprocessor defines. The OP didn't mention being memory constrained. Of course there are a multitude of options if one is memory constrained, like dynamically allocating memory (once) when the feature is chosen, storing data in EEPROM, or reusing variables. That's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If the feature selection is not at runtime but is at compile time you could do it like this:

```
#define FEATURE1 true   // Feature 1 is enabled

void setup() {
    #if FEATURE1
    setup1(); //only runs if 1st feature chosen
    #endif
    setup2();
    setup3();
}

void loop() {
    #if FEATURE1
    loop1(); //only runs if 1st feature chosen
    #endif
    loop2();
    loop3();
}

void setup1(void) {}
void setup2(void) {}
void setup3(void) {}

void loop1(void) {}
void loop2(void) {}
void loop3(void) {}
```